# Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix

We are using **postfix** on **centos** as a mail server to send out newsletters. but in the mail log file I can see that many receivers rejected our newsletters.  and with the help of mxtoolbox, I found a warning message for our mail server - "*reverse DNS does not match SMTP banner*".

my hostname is **webserver.XXXX.com** that has both outgoing / incoming ip to **109.XX.XX.93**,
when I use reverse DNS lookup tool, the ip adress 109.XX.XX.93 resolved to *webserver.XXXX.com.XX.XX.109.in-addr.arpa*. Should I actually expect this to be  **webserver.XXXX.com**, if it has to be correct? and I guess this is the case that mxtoolbox give "reverse DNS does not match SMTP banner" message?

If I *telnet 109.XX.XX.93 25*, i got *220 webserver.XXX.com ESMTP Postfix*.

Comment: Banner match and "no relay allowed" are totally different issues. Both are critical but still two issues.

Comment: Thanks for advice. but i want to fix this reverse DNS thing first

Comment: Then why the heck do you even mention the relay issues? Trying to confuse people?

Comment: just look at the title of the post, and the question in my post. stop commenting if you don't have solution for the reverse DNS issue. thanks.

Comment: I Have a solution. The solution is simple - fix the reverse mapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, both name-to-ip and ip-to-name mapping must match exactly, that is:

`109.XX.XX.93` must resolve to `webserver.XXXX.com` and `webserver.XXXX.com` must resolve to `109.XX.XX.93` exactly.

Then additionally, the SMTP banner presented must match the same hostname.

If your IP address reverse lookup does not match `webserver.XXXX.com`, you should contact your hosting provider for instructions on how to fix it, as it is the IP block owner that controls reverse DNS records.

Comment: Thanks. I contacted my ISP, and they corrected the error. now our hostname and Ip adresse matching in reverse DNS. Great help, thanks.